# Error "close (transport close)" on Socket client side

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, haproxy

In my express/socket app, (which is running behind HAproxy server), I am using sticky session(cookie based) to route requests to same worker. I have total 16 processes running (8 /machine- 2 machines). Socket session data is being stored in Redis adapter.

The problem I have is, when an event is fired from server, client can't receive it.  Inspite, it will keep throwing disconnection errors, after every few seconds (4-5) :

[image]

**Update** : It will only fire event if transport was opened when event was fired, which is getting closed instantly, and than restarting.

Can someone please suggest something on this..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. It was **timeout client** which was set to too low in HAproxy config. Increasing it, fixed the issue.

Comment: What was the original timeout? I set it to 10s still facing issue